# Постановка запятых (необычный случай)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, определения

Мотыльки летели со всех сторон и падали, обожжённые, на скатерть.

По какому правилу происходит постановка запятых?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причастие ***обожжённые*** обособляется по следующему правилу:

> **7.** Одиночное (нераспространенное) определение **обособляется:**
> <...>
> **3)** если оторвано в тексте от существительного: *Глаза смыкались и, **полузакрытые**, тоже улыбались* (Т.); *На лавке, **разбросанные**, лежали поршни, ружьё* (Л. Т.); *Настасья Петровна ещё раз обняла Егорушку, обозвала его ангельчиком и, **заплаканная**, стала собирать на стол* (Ч.)...

Источник: [Обособленные определения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108) (справочник Розенталя).